# What is the difference between `BeginSubscribeToStreamingNotifications` and `SubscribeToStreamingNotifications`

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I see there's a new version of the managed EWS API v1.2  that targets Exchange 2010 SP2.

What is the difference between the 2 streaming notification subscriptions calls? I don't have VS at my disposal so I can't find out for myself. This question pretty much works for all subscription mechanism (push, pull, streaming) as well as syncing folder items since EWS 1.2 seems to introduce a lot of new `Begin` and `End` functions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually the methods that start with `BeginXXX` mark the start of an asynchronous call to a method, which needs to be followed at some point by `EndXXX`.